# Need advice if this wiring is okay (adding outlet into a run)

Tags: electrical, wiring

If I didn't live remotely and I could hire an electrician I would, but it's not an option where I live. So any help you can give, I really appreciate. Thank you. My existing wiring in my water closet has a light in the middle of a run, the wiring looks like this:

[image: Existing Wiring]

I have the need to add an outlet for a water filter (uses minimal power) Is it okay to drop in an outlet into the run, before or after the light? Example wiring scenarios:

[image: Optional wiring idea]

or before the light:

[image: Other idea]

Comment: Please consider posting the maximum current of each device on the circuit and the circuit breaker's current rating.  In addition, publishing which country or more will enable others to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An outlet in a bathroom has to be on its own dedicated 20 amp circuit, but this is its lighting circuit, so I *think* it's ok (?) either way (assuming those aren't one and the same already).

Run a new leg from the light's box, because if you splice into a conduit, the wires wont be long enough (per code), or you'll have to run a bit of new wire to replace some of the old, and some for the new run. And unless you have a wire-in-conduit conduit cutter, likely you'll have to replace the whole run from both directions. Or have to pull 'em all out, which is silly. Just do a new run from the closest box.

Comment: So basically, just run a wire out from the current light box (hot to join the hot, neutral to neutral, ground to ground) and out into a new outlet box?

Comment: @CabinDIY - Pretty much. My only concern (other than you're a novice...) is that you might be stealing it from what's *supposed* to be a dedicated circuit (... there's worse things). - And splicing into a conduit is like rehab; can-of-worms. A new run is like new construction; there's no surprises.

Comment: From what I can tell, the run goes from this light in this closet, to an outlet in an adjacent pantry, and a third outlet near the kitchen.

Comment: Not so clear if this is conduit. Drawing shows black tape on a white wire - as I understand it, that is legal for cables (e.g., Romex) but not for wire in conduit. So if that part is correct then this may really be cables, not conduit.

Comment: @manassehkatz - Splicing into a Romex run would require *two* boxes. I'd like to see where it says you can't re-identify in EMT. I do remember something about it not being ok for neutrals though (one way, but not the other).

Comment: I'm no pro. But I'm pretty sure I've seen Harper mention it a few times.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell if you are in cable or conduit.   Cable is a stiff but flexible plastic jacket with several wires very tightly wrapped.  Conduit is plastic or metal pipe  with wires loosely added.

If you have an inline conduit, and you want to add a box, that is easily done.  However you have to pull out the wires before you begin.  When you put the wires back in, you will find they are too short for all you need to do, so you will need to either replace parts of the wire runs, or have the existing wire-run *run right through your new box without stopping*, then add an additional set of wires to the next box up or down.  I use this "run thru and follow it" technique when a box is getting crowded.  **If your existing conduit is metal, stay in metal**.

If you have cable, then you need to install 2 boxes, make good use of the existing cable run, and install new cable between the 2 boxes. Alternately you can replace all the cable between the new box and the next existing box down the line.

The reason for this in both cases is that you need to have *considerable* length of wire at the box.  You cannot "runt" it with an inch of slack on each wire and the wire nuts crammed into the back of the box.  What you want is 9-10" of length on each wire. The legal bare minimum is 6" past the end of the cable clamp or pipe, plus 3" beyond the wall surface, but the legal minimum is cramped to work in.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you in the world ?  In the U.S. lights don't require GFCI , but everything else does,  if in the U.S. you can have a light there but it requires a wet or damp listing. Not sure on your side of the pond from the text.

Answer (score 0):

### Since this is a dedicated outlet for a dedicated appliance, having it on the lighting circuit should be OK, but with caveats

Under the NEC, an outlet intended to serve the bathroom at large either needs to be on a 20A circuit dedicated to that bathroom, or on a 20A circuit dedicated to bathroom receptacles.  However, since you are installing something for the sake of fitting a specific appliance, tapping it from the lighting circuit stands a decent chance of being acceptable to the local Code inspectors. However, to maximize the chance it will be acceptable, I would use a *single* receptacle instead of a *duplex* receptacle; that way, it's less likely someone will see it as a general-purpose receptacle outlet.